# How to make avdec_h264 use custom buffer pool to dump decoded data

Tags: gstreamer

Am using Gstreamer-1.0. I've a pool of display buffers which I want 'avdec_h264' decoder plugin to use to dump decoded raw data. Currently I'm doing a 'memcpy' of decoded raw buffers to the display buffers which is deteriorating the framerate. So, how can I make 'avdec_h264' use the display buffers directly to dump the decoded data from application and avoid the 'memcpy'.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think avdec_h264 will support dumping directly into a hardware memory buffer, if that's what you're seeking.  The caps are:

```
  SRC template: 'src'
    Availability: Always
    Capabilities:
      video/x-raw
                 format: { I420, YUY2, RGB, BGR, Y42B, Y444, YUV9, Y41B, GRAY8, RGB8P, I420, Y42B, Y444, UYVY, NV12, NV21, ARGB, RGBA, ABGR, BGRA, GRAY16_BE, GRAY16_LE, A420, RGB16, RGB15, I420_10BE, I420_10LE, I422_10BE, I422_10LE, Y444_10BE, Y444_10LE, GBR, GBR_10BE, GBR_10LE }
```

What hardware and OS are you running on?  What resolutions are you decoding from?  Are you trying to get the decoded video into system memory or graphics card memory?  If you're running on the Pi you might want to try their OMX libs.  If it's an Intel PC you could try vaapi.

We use memcpy of decoded buffers all the time in our app many times without performance issue, but we run it on i7 chips...

Comment: Am using Android Kitkat on Nexus 5. I would like to dump the output in camera display buffers so that default Android camera app will show this decoded video. I dont have much knowledge of camera display buffers as I only get a handle of each buffer for one frame to dump everytime.

Comment: You might want to add some tags related to Android and KitKat.  It sounds as though you just want raw images from the camera and there should be an element to get those without going through a decode I'd think.